# Thunderbird and Firefox "profiles" disappear when using updated versions of software

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

I had to reinstall my computer, and tried to "import" my previous Thunderbird and Firefox settings by copying my old `.mozilla` and `.thunderbird` folders into my new instillation.

If I use old versions of Firefox and Thuderbird, everything works okay (Thunderbird 60.9.01 and Firefox 66.0.5). However, if I install new releases of Firefox and Thunderbird, they prompt me to "create a new profile," and when I create the profile, all previous settings are ignored (mail-folders in Thunderbird, browser history and passwords in Firefox, etc.).

Any clues about what is going on, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you put the respective folders? What about the profiles.ini file? How do you install the new releases?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1260190

Comment: Originally, when I would update from my previous installation, things would work fine. BUt this time I had to reinstall my computer from scratch. and when I copied the whole ~/.thunderbird folder, it just didn't work.

Comment: I installed Thunderbird from the Ubuntu packages.  If I install Ubuntu, and then copy the contents of my profile folder into the newly-created profile folder, when I start thunderbird it tells me that a new version may have changed my profile, and prompts me to create a new one, or quit. If I create a new one, a new profile folder is created in ~/.thunderbird , and my configuration and mailboxes are still not found. WHat's going on?

Comment: Now I've tried copying the contents of the old profile into the newly-created profile folder, but keeping the new compatibility.in file.  I am able to open Thunderbird without being prompted to create a new profile. Looks like my accounts settings are there (I can see them in the "Get all messages" drop-down menu). BUt the mailboxes are not there. And somehow it's impossible to open the "accounts" or preferences settings.....

Comment: running thunderbrid --profilemanager and then creating a new profile and selecting the old folder doesn't work, wither -- I see the email accounds, but not my mailboxes.  HOw can I solve this problem!?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 67 and later use a [changed name scheme for profile folders](https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1264072) to allow different profiles for different "channels" of firefox to live together. Profiles associated with the stable release have "-release" appended to their profile name. The same applies for more recent Thunderbird versions.

So for this single time, copy the contents of your old profile over to the newly created profile with the "*.default-release" name to restore your settings.